How to change video size in Gitlab?
I have to the following code to display a video in a Gitlab ticket:
![disclaimer-buggy.mp4](/uploads/cb7763bebe939311c85fadb5f4f2b27e/disclaimer-buggy.mp4)

Is there any way to limit this video to a certain size instead of full size?

From https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#change-the-image-or-video-dimensions
![alt text](img/markdown_logo.png "Title Text"){width=100 height=100px}

